# Rename or delete tags

Tags: support, tags

I just saw [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/436/49). It first only contained a "stanley-kubrick"-tag and now somebody also added a "stephen-spielberg"-tag. But well, I think he's spelled ["Steven"](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000229/) rather than "Stephen". But the problem is, I cannot retag this question anymore.

Now the simple question (with a maybe obvious answer) is, how to rename or delete this tag or just retag this question? Or should I just ask the author to retag it? But then, how to get rid of this wrong tag (I guess there is no other relevant Stephen Spielberg that this tag may be used for).

Comment: Oops - my mistake.  I am however only 14 reputation points from being able to correct my mistake with Steven's name through a tag synonym, which I will do so when I can. I even looked up the spelling of his last name to make sure and didn't notice.

Comment: I would also edit the post and substitute a tag with the correct spelling, but an edit is already in progress (possibly someone else fixing this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, since this was my mistake, I can do the research to answer your question.

Anyone with 200 reputation can re-tag a question, which will enable someone to substitute a correct tag for an incorrect one in a post.

Anyone with 1250 reputation gains the 'create tag synonym' privilege, which will allow them to propose fixes to tags (which are approved with others).

Comment: But I had already over 200 rep and there was no "retag" link under the question (I would have just done that, of course). Can you explain that? Maybe only the first retag is allowed? Or maybe it's 225 rep or something the like?

Comment: I got the 200 from the reputations page (http://movies.stackexchange.com/privileges/retag-questions) so it is strange that you cannot retag.  Do other questions have a retag link for you?

Comment: If not, I would raise a 'bug' and 'support' tagged question here.

Comment: I can even retag the mentioned question now, but I'm sure I couldn't (and neither edit) when I wanted. Maybe it was just some synchronization error.

Comment: Cool - it had been uneditable due to an unapproved prior edit, so perhaps that was it.

Comment: Ah ok, and since I don't have editing priviliges (and therefore cannot approve) it just didn't show the links. Sounds reasonable.

Comment: The question probably had a pending edit. When this is the case, you cannot propose new edits until the pending edit has been resolved (either approved or rejected).

Comment: But you *can* hit the ol' flag button to harass a mod about it, so you aren't entirely without recourse when a question has a pending edit.

Comment: @iandotkelly: please could you create synonyms from stephen-spielberg (and spielberg) that map to steven-spielberg?

Comment: @Hugo: I can propose synonyms, but someone else will have to approve.  I will do that now.

Comment: @Hugo: Sorry, it won't let me as I need a score of 5 on the steven-spielberg tag to do this.  We'll have to wait until community moderators are appointed, and you can ask one of them.  Discussion on this is happening on meta now.